# Why does cell waste energy in meiosis, between meiosis 1&2

Tags: dna, chromosome, meiosis, cell-division, chromatin

As far as I have learnt about meiosis I have read that anaphase 1 is followed by telophase 2 where chromosomes change back to reticulum.but in the very next stage i.e prophase 2 they again start condensing to form chromosomes again.i have also heard that is most species, cytokinesis is simultaneous and not successive( which means that the 4 cells undergo cytokinesis together)..

If this is the case, then what is the need for a cell to waste its energy on making chromosomes back to reticulum at the end of meiosis 1, and again condense it in the very next step
Can't it directly continue on to prophase 2!

It sounds ridiculous,...but I beleive there must be a reason behind it, because the last thing a cell would want to do is to waste its energy in such things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can someone please give an answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a phase between meiosis 1 and meiosis 2 called [Interkinesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interkinesis?wprov=sfla1).
During this phase centrosomes or centriole pairs undergo replication in animal cells, which is important for bringing true haploidy.

Refer - [meiosis-ii](https://openoregon.pressbooks.pub/mhccmajorsbio/chapter/meiosis-ii/)